# Data type error in contains

Tags: java

I am trying to write some code to validate a line entry by the user. I need to ensure that the user has inputted a ":" as this is the line delimiter however I am getting an error.

This is the error:

> The method contains(CharSequence) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char)

Is there any way I can fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
public class REQ2
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {

     String playername;      
     String line;
     String[] list = new String[100];
     int count = 0;  
     int score;
     int time;
     int totalScore =0;

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 


      System.out.println("Please enter your name");

      playername = sc.nextLine();

      if(playername.equals(""))
      {
          System.out.println("Player name was not entered please try again");
          System.exit(0);
      }

      System.out.println("Please enter your game achivements (Game name:score:time played) E.g. Minecraft:14:2332");

      while (count < 100){

             line = sc.nextLine();

             if(line.equals("quit")){
                  break;
                  }

            if(!(line.contains(':'))){ //error on this line
                System.out.println("Please enter achivements with the proper \":\" sepration\n");  
            }

             list[count]=line;
            System.out.println("list[count]" + list[count]);

            count++;

        for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
          line=list[i];
          String[] elements =line.split(":");   

          if (line.length() !=3){
                System.out.println("Error please try again, Please enter in the following format:\nGame name:score:timeplayed");
                   break;
         }   

          score = Integer.parseInt(elements[1].trim());          
          time=Integer.parseInt(elements[2].trim());


               }

           }
      }

 }
```

Comment: A `char` is not a `CharSequence`, so you can't pass one in.  Instead pass in a `String`: `if (!line.contains(":")){`

Answer (score 5):

instead of

```
 if(!(line.contains(':'))){ //error on this line
```

Use

```
 if(!(line.contains(":"))){ //error on this line
```

As from String java doc

> contains
>   public boolean contains(CharSequence s)
>   Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.
>   **Parameters**:
>   s - the sequence to search for
>   **Returns**:
>   true if this string contains s, false otherwise

If you see the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) of contains method

> Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified
>   sequence of char values. Parameters: s the sequence to search for
>   Returns: true if this string contains s, false otherwise Throws:
>   NullPointerException if s is null Since:
>   1.5

```
2114    public boolean More ...contains(CharSequence s) {
2115        return indexOf(s.toString()) > -1;
2116    }
```

Comment: Please mark the solution as ACCEPTED if it helped you to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You character needs to be in double quotes to make it a string

```
":"
```